# Using RANK function in Tableau on a Combined column. However, display individual columns as well

Tags: tableau-api, rank

I am using RANK function in Tableau and I am displaying the Rank of calculated measure (Eg: 1 to 50)
The calculated Measure I have is Total Amount for Combined Periods.

When there is no Period displayed on the dashboard, the Total Amount is the sum of both periods and this is exactly what I want. I am good in this case.

However, When I want to display the Period in the Rows, the Total Amount changes to "Total Amount for Period 1 and Total Amount for Period 2".

How can I add a different axis to show Individual Periods as well as Rank of Total Amount for Combined Period?

I guess this might come down to Dual axis in Tableau and I believe this is not available yet and users are voting for this in Ideas.

Comment: Show your code please. We need example data and expected output.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with SQL or SQL-Server, so probably should remove those tags.